# What is the point of Encrypt connection string in web.config?

Tags: asp.net

Why encrypt the connection string in the web.config? If I'm not mistaken the IIS doesn't serve web.config and if someone is able to hacked into your server to get the web.config then it's GG already. Is there any reason to encrypt anything in web.config? Isn't it unnecessary?

Comment: You may not want developers on a team to see the user/password to access the database directly.

Comment: especially in larger corps the people working on web servers may not be people working on the data servers.

Comment: I've seen all too often that developers have an unsecure file download ashx in their application (vulnerable of canonical representation attacks) that allow the config file to be downloaded. Example: `download.ashx?file=..\..\..\web.config`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a need to secure connection string in web.config?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10417096/is-there-a-need-to-secure-connection-string-in-web-config)

Comment: I guess it make sense in larger team but it feel inconvenience in a small team. Especially the previous team use their own encryption method and not the standard MS method.

Comment: @Liu, thanks for the link. I didn't find that post. I'll read up on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't rule out that the web box is compromised - this shouldn't mean that your db gets compromised as well.
Also, you don't want the web admins to know passwords to databases.

You need to remember that config files cannot be obtained by the browser just because `.config` extension is in the list of restrictions in IIS metadata. It may be possible to get them from the server in other way or some misconfiguration problem may allow them to be downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

I would think it's more an organisational problem / compliance.

For example, you may have a "production" team / elevated position that can access "live" data, whilst devs may have read only access via the Application, and you'd rather that they didn't have the username / password - ergo, encrypt the connection string.

Or should disgruntled / thoughtless dev email the web.config to mates / home / hotmail it means that all and sundry couldn't get the username / password to access the database.

Ultimately, it's just another layer of security - Why have a gate to your drive when you lock your front door? (if you have a drive with a gate of course!)