# Securely encrypting / decrypting appsettings.json on server

Tags: encryption, asp.net-core, connection-string

How do I protect the encryption key used to encrypt sensitive data in my web application's `appsettings.json`?

I would like to protect sensitive data in my web application's config.

In ASP.NET MVC4 applications we did it like this:

1. Sensitive data (e.g. password in a connection string) is not added directly to `web.config` (or `web.prod.config` etc.), instead a placeholder variable is written.
2. At deployment time, our deployment service (Octopus) would retrieve sensitive data from its secure storage and overwrite the variable in the `web.config`.
3. The deployment process would then encrypt sensitive sections of the web.config using `aspnet_regiis.exe`.

Now we are using ASP.NET Core the process we are following is a bit different.

1. `appsettings.json` holds the placeholder variables for sensitive data,
   similar to how web.config worked before.
2. Deployment process substitutes placeholders with sensitive data from it's secure store as before.
3. Instead of using `aspnet_regiis`, I believe I need to:

   a) make my own custom tool to encrypt parts of the `appsettings.json` file.

   b) make a custom configuration provider that can decrypt (all / parts of) the `appsettings.json`

What I don't understand is how to protect the encryption key used for (a) and (b). The old way leveraged the server's machine key to encrypt the file.

The threat I am trying to mitigate is someone gaining access to the `appsettings.json` on the server and reading sensitive data out of it (e.g. database password etc.)

I am also intrested in alternative ways to mitigate this threat and/or other problems with this approach in general.

Comment: Are you running on Azure? That has a secure way to store secrets external to your application.

Comment: @JimW No, I'm not on Azure.

Comment: Even though you are not running on Azure, I would still recommend using [Azure Key Vault](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/key-vault/) for storing your secrets. For starters, it is very cheap (~$0.0159 / 10 000 operations) and secondly it can be accessed from anywhere, even outside Azure. You can have an in-memory cache so a REST call to Key Vault is made only at the start of your application (or when your cache expires), thereby preventing any further latencies. Third, this is the recommended approach by Microsoft.

Comment: @ThePretendProgrammer Your comment is the best answer so far, but I think it needs to be in an answer instead of a comment to receive the bounty.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not "trust" server - you can't protect "secrets" you store inside this server.

Explanation:

No matter what "secured" (=unsecured) scheme you invent - when application starts is must be able do "decrypt" secrets into some "usable" form.

This means that all "keys" (certs, etc) required to "decrypt" must exist on this server and be accessible to app (otherwise app can't start).

This means that some bad guy who access the server and app also can access all "keys" on it, and "decrypt" your secrets. May be by copying files, may be by decompiling you app, may be dumping you app memory - but it can.

There is no absolute protection.

Comment: Yeah, I get where you're coming from, but still feel encrypting secrets in appsettings.json is worth it for all the reasons in the accepted answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10417096/177018). E.g. when attacker has partial access to server or config file only. What is best / most pragmatic way to store keys in that scenario in ASP.NET Core to give similar level of protection to aspnet_regiis using machine keys?

Comment: This is not correct, in depth security is very important, and if your server has been compromised doesn't necessarily mean the attacker has also gained the permission to execute commands as administrator.

Comment: @Norcino, no need for admin access. If app have enough rights to access some secrets (it has, otherwise it won't work), then any principal with same "low" access rights can access same secrets. Main question here is WHO bad guy is, because "appsettings.json" is inaccessible for "regular" visitor. And if topicstarter want to protect from his own webserver admins... it's impossible.

Comment: @Dmtry I agree with your point of view but this does not cover the possibility that due to exploit or wrong configuration, unauthorized users gain read access to the website folder, which would allow to read the configuration file.
Using a secure in depth principle, you have to assume a breach is possible and you need to act to limit the damage and information disclosure. The breach cannot be assumed to be such that the intruder has managed to impersonate an admin.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you're not interested in "ways" to do it, but in the recommended approach ASP.NET Core supports. While other answers here has mentioned the Azure KeyVault as a good storage for sensitive information, it's not the way to store it rather the actual storage.
ASP.NET Core supports the notion of `overridable configuration`. That is, multiple configuration providers can be registered in the configuration system and the order they are registered in matters. Each registered one overrides settings from previous providers - those it has of course.
In other words, if you have registered the standard JSON configuration provider and then also let's assume a database configuration provider, then those settings, which both providers have, will be getting the values defined by the later defined provider - the database provider.
So in your situation, here what I'd suggest to do:

1. Have all the default configuration providers registered as is.
2. Register **Azure Key Vault** (or similar secret storage based provider) configuration provider in the end.
3. Use certificate authentication to authenticate with Key Vault and read sensitive settings.

While this is not 1:1 mapping to what your current process is, it is inline with ASP.NET Core principles.

You can read more about ASP.NET Configuration at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/index?tabs=basicconfiguration

Here you can read about Azure KeyVault configuration provider: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?tabs=aspnetcore2x

If certificate based auth is not an option for you, consider storing `ClientId` and `ClientSecret` used to connect to Azure Key Vault service in environment variables, and use an appropriate configuration provider (`AddEnvironmentVariables()` extension method will do it) to access those.

This setup will be really secure. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I am converting the comment into an answer :)

Even though you are not running on Azure, I would still recommend using [Azure Key Vault](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/key-vault/) for storing your secrets. For starters, it is very cheap (~$0.0159 / 10 000 operations) and secondly it can be accessed from anywhere, even outside Azure. Additionally, the secrets in Azure Key Vault can be versioned which is a nice feature to support multiple versions of a secret per environment (only for pre-production since Production should have a key vault of its own). The Key Vault [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault/) package has operations to retrieve and add secrets within .NET Core. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.keyvault.keyvaultclient?view=azure-dotnet) is a link to the documentation.

You can have an in-memory cache so a REST call (or Key Vault package method call) to Key Vault is made only at the start of your application (or when your cache expires), thereby preventing any further latencies. Third, this is the recommended approach by Microsoft.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This does not solve the problem for isolated systems with no access to external resources or where security policies do not allow to use cloud services.

Answer (score 1):

If someone unauthorized gains access to the server, well, stealing the secrets - say, database connection strings, is just a small part of the problem (@Dmitry's answer).

Since you want a better control over the secret data or configuration, it is *okay* to slightly deviate from the *usual* `appsettings.json`-based approach.

You may take the secrets, asymmetrically encrypt them with the server's certificate, store them in a separate file (it could be another `.json` file for that matter) then read the file and decrypt the secrets at startup / on each web request. This way, the secrets are almost as safe as the server's certificate / private key.

Another option: symmetrically encrypt the secrets and feed the password to the web application at start-up so that it can decrypt the secrets. When the process hosting the web application restarts, you have to feed the password again (you can engage a separate machine to periodically feed it or so).

Also see [Data Protection in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/), [Data Protection samples](https://github.com/aspnet/DataProtection/tree/dev/samples).

Sometimes, long and cryptic passwords or simple obfuscation of an otherwise human-friendly password are sufficient. That is, just protecting against eavesdropping. Say, somebody sitting next to the admin won't be able to read and memorize a string of apparently random characters.